# ShellCode not running as expected - showing segmentation fault core dump

Tags: shellcode

I  have already run this command. But my shellcode is not working for me:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack test.c -o test
./test
```

> ```
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

Here is my shellcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
unsigned char code[] = "\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {   int foo_value = 0;
 
int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;   foo_value = foo();
 
printf("%d\n", foo_value); }
```

Here is my operating system:

```
uname -a
Linux AAAA 5.13.0-30-generic #33~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 7 14:25:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have already identified the location using the following command:

```
gcc -c -O3 ex.c
objdump ex.o -d
```

> ```
> ex.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
>
> Disassembly of section .text:
>
> 0000000000000000 <foo>:    
> 0:    f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64     
> 4:    b8 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%eax
> 9:    c3                      retq
> ```

Comment: You have code as a *global* variable. Global data is not executable (by default). Your GCC parameter only disables the execution prevention of stack contents (*local*, non-static variables), but not of global variables.

Answer (score 3):

The argument `-z execstack` only allows stack to execute code, but the `code` is a global variable, which is not on stack, so you can do some simple changes to make your code work.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int foo_value = 0;
    unsigned char code[] = "\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
    int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;
    foo_value = foo();
    printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple **HACK** for `gcc` would be to make the `char` array as `const` That makes the bytes go in `.rodata` which is usally mapped within the same pages as `.text` and has the same `rx` permission.

This worked for me without any additional flag.

```
[/tmp] cat x.c
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned char code[] = "\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc3";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int foo_value = 0;

  int(*foo)() = (int (*) ())&code;
  foo_value = foo();

  printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
[/tmp] make x
cc     x.c   -o x
[/tmp] ./x
10
```

Comment: FYI: in my case it leads to `Segmentation fault` when using `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack`. GCC 9.4.0, Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Any ideas? The `code` is in `.rodata`.